# Search multiple words and intelligent sorting in sqlite

Tags: sqlite, android-sqlite

I have an app where a user can type a search query that will get a result from an SQLite database.
If a user type `word1 word2 word3`, I use the following query :

```
SELECT * FROM myTable 
WHERE myColumn LIKE word1 
   OR myColumn LIKE word2 
   OR myColumn LIKE word3 
ORDER BY myColumn
```

I get all values that have at least one of the three words typed in. I would like to get the results that match the three values first, then those who match two values and then those who match only one value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sum the boolean expressions in your `WHERE` clause and order descending:

```
SELECT * 
FROM myTable 
WHERE myColumn LIKE 'word1'  OR myColumn LIKE 'word2' OR myColumn LIKE 'word3' 
ORDER BY ((myColumn LIKE 'word1') + (myColumn LIKE 'word2') + (myColumn LIKE 'word3')) DESC
```

Note that if you want exact match of the words you should use `=` instead of `LIKE`, but if you want partial match you must concatenate the `%` wildcard:

```
myColumn LIKE '%' || 'word1' || '%'
```

or:

```
myColumn LIKE '%word1%'
```

Comment: what is the difference between `LIKE word` and `LIKE %word%` ?

Comment: `x LIKE 'abc'` is equivalent to `x = 'abc'` except perhaps that LIKE might be case insensitive. But `x LIKE '%abc%'` means `x` contains `'abc'`.

Comment: Check this: https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-like/

Comment: @Arcyno Correct, because `LIKE` has lower precedence than `+`: https://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html and thanks for th eedit.